# Remove all items from Safari 10.10.1 reading list

Tags: macos, safari, reading-list

I wish to remove all sites from the reading list. Under the spectacles is a list of sites previously visited. I now wish to remove all sites on this list.

Answer (score 2):

Right-click on an item in the list and choose Clear All Items.

Reading List is not a list of sites you previously listed, but rather a list of sites you specifically added to the list using the + button to the left of the address bar.